# How to host python cgi script with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` or `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000`?

Tags: python, hosting, cgi, simplehttpserver

When I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` or `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` in my shell I am hosting the content of my current directory to the internet.

I would like to make the following cgi_script.py work correctly using the above command in the command line when I browse to `192.xxx.x.xx:8000/cgi_script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

But this script is displayed literally and not only the "Hello World!" part.
Btw I changed the file permissions to 755 for cgi_script.py as well as the folder I am hosting it from.

Comment: For people trying this out on mac or linux, be sure to have permissions that allow executing the file. In other words: `chmod +x cgi-bin/cgi_script.py`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try with `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000`.

Note that you have to move the script to a `cgi-bin` or `htbin` directory in order to be runnable.

Comment: This doesn't change anything unfortunately. (I don't understand why not).

Comment: @Bentley4 - Please see the updated answer about the CGI directory.

Comment: I tried with the directory being named cgi_bin, htbin and even cgi-bin. None worked appropriately.

Comment: @Bentley4 - My bad! It should be `cgi-bin` (use the Source!). Corrected. And it worked for me. But note that the url should be changed accordingly: `http://xxxx:8000/cgi-bin/cgi_script.py`.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I did wrong there. I have to run `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` from the directory one level under the `cgi-bin` directory. If you run it with ´cgi-bin´ as your current directory it won't work, strange.

Comment: @Bentley4 - Not so strange, it is a classic old restriction to avoid running random programs as if they were CGI when they were not intended to be used that way.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer saved me!

Answer (score 6):

SO doesn't allow me to comment so I'm adding this as a separate answer, addition to rodrigo's.

You can use another parameter `cgi_directories` which defaults to `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']`. More info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories)

Answer (score 2):

In Python3 the command line is simply

```sh
python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Comment: and yes: the script needs to reside in '/cgi-bin'

Comment: your command fails with the error `Unknown option: -p` which makes sense because you are giving `http.server` as if it were a set of short options. It does not work like this. Instead it should be `python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue I found that depending on which directory you are in when you run the `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` command yields different results. When attempting to run the command while in the cgi-bin directory the browser continued to return the raw script code. once I cd'ed one level higher and ran the `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` command again my script began executing.

Answer (score 0):

@Bentley4 -ifyou are still not able to do,
try importing cgi.

**#!C:\Python34\python.exe -u**
import cgi
print ("Content-type:text/html")

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, run the `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` command same menu level with cgi-bin,and move cgi_script.py into cgi-bin folder.In browser type http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/cgi_script.py