# Pushing to a git repository hosted locally over HTTP

Tags: git

I wish to push to a git repository hosted on `http://localhost:8000/tehCode.git` servered using the `python -m "SimpleHTTPServer"` command.

I receive an error

```
error: Cannot access URL http://localhost:8000/tehCode.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I can clone this repository just fine, but I can't push to it.
How can I do this assuming I want to still use the Python SimpleHTTPServer ?

I've already looked at

1. [Cannot push Git to remote repository with http/https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264949/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-with-http-https)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/473177/git-push-fatal-failed

But they seem to be working with Apache and most of the solutions are by editing Apache's config file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you hosting a repo on a server, locally?

Comment: Trying to setup a continuous Integration testing platform.

Comment: I have no idea what HTTP method git push would use, but that's not important. What's important is that *you* have an idea, and then *show us* what you tried to implement for that. Does your server implement the correct method handler at all?

Comment: I haven't written any method handlers for the server, git update-server-info seems to generate all the required urls. I don't have much knowledge about what git update-server-info does, But now that you mention it, there doesn't seem to be any method in the server itself to handle a git upload request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a SimpleHTTPServer, you are using the so called dumb http protocol. It is called dumb because it has no knowledge about git at all. Because of that, pushing to such a server does not work, because the http server has no clue what to do with the request git is making.

Git has a cgi script, called git-http-backend, which is made to allow for pushing over http by using the smart http protocol.

I have no experience with this, but you could look at pythons [CGIHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396330/how-to-host-python-cgi-script-with-python-m-simplehttpserver-8000-or-python) which you could direct to git-http-backend.

But the easiest way is to use [apache](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html).

Answer (score -1):

Why use HTTP if it is local? Could just `git push where/the/repo/lives` should do.